# Google apps script: Parsing JSON and write them to google spreadsheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've managed to download a JSON file using the Google Apps Script. Soon, I've found that my JSON is somewhat complex than examples on the internet (including here).

```
var json = {"block1":[{"TRD_DD":"2021/12/22","MKTCAP":"2,208,300,470,743,887","FORN_HD_MKTCAP":"740,740,079,190,175","MKTCAP_RTO":"33.54","LIST_SHRS":"61,701,475,584","FORN_HD_SHRS":"11,191,374,601","LIST_SHRS_RTO":"18.14"},{"TRD_DD":"2021/12/21","MKTCAP":"2,200,896,109,564,335","FORN_HD_MKTCAP":"736,382,905,931,787","MKTCAP_RTO":"33.46","LIST_SHRS":"61,701,475,584","FORN_HD_SHRS":"11,198,948,564","LIST_SHRS_RTO":"18.15"},{"TRD_DD":"2021/12/20","MKTCAP":"2,191,456,183,748,063","FORN_HD_MKTCAP":"731,379,899,525,089","MKTCAP_RTO":"33.37","LIST_SHRS":"61,698,916,232","FORN_HD_SHRS":"11,215,916,966","LIST_SHRS_RTO":"18.18"}],"CURRENT_DATETIME":"2021.12.22 PM 04:24:06"}
```

There are more arrays in "Block1" but I shortened the length. please consider multiple more rows (about 500 rows, I think)

I'd like to give different column names like "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG" instead of "TRD_DD", "MKTCAP", "FORN_HD_MKTCAP", "MKTCAP_RTO", "LIST_SHRS", "FORN_HD_SHRS", "LIST_SHRS_RTO".
Each value for the same name should be inserted in each row (sorry, StackOverflow does not allow me to insert images. It is very difficult to explain).

and if possible, I'd like to change all numbers to numeric not string.

I am a beginner in handling javascript, so it is very difficult!!!
Is there anyone to help me? If any, it will be greatly appreciated.

***Addendum

Here is my original script

```
function foreign_daily(){
  
  var url = 'http://data.krx.co.kr/comm/bldAttendant/getJsonData.cmd';
  var formData = {
      "bld": "dbms/MDC/STAT/standard/MDCSTAT03601",
      "mktId": "STK",
      "strtDd": "20211220",
      "endDd": "20211222",
      "share": "2",
      "money": "3",
      "csvxls_isNo": "false"};
  

  var headers = { 
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Accept-Language": "ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                 
      "Origin": "http://data.krx.co.kr",
      "Referer": "http://data.krx.co.kr/contents/MDC/MDI/mdiLoader/index.cmd?menuId=MDC0201020503",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.118 Whale/2.11.126.23 Safari/537.36",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    };
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(formData));

  var options = { 
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'headers': headers,
    'payload': formData
  };

  var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  

// Object for converting the keys.
  var obj = {"TRD_DD": "AAA", "MKTCAP": "BBB", "FORN_HD_MKTCAP": "CCC", "MKTCAP_RTO": "DDD", "LIST_SHRS": "EEE", "FORN_HD_SHRS": "FFF", "LIST_SHRS_RTO": "GGG"};

// Converting keys.
  json.block1 = json.block1.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [obj[k], v.includes(",") ? v.split(",").map(e => Number(e)) : v])));

  console.log(json)

// Put the values to Spreadsheet.
  var header = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG"];
  var values = json.block1.flatMap(o => {
    var temp = header.map(h => o[h]);
    var max = Math.max(...temp.map(r => Array.isArray(r) ? r.length : 1));
    temp = temp.map(r => {
      if (Array.isArray(r)) {
        return r.length == max ? r : [...r, ...Array(max - r.length).fill("")];
      }
      return [r, ...Array(max - 1).fill("")]; // or return Array(max).fill(r);
    })
    return temp[0].map((_, c) => temp.map(r => r[c]));
  });
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet126"); // Please set the sheet name.
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

and now it says

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
foreign_daily   @ Foreign_daily.gs:42
```

Thanks again, Tanaike!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXF8s.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to change the keys from `"TRD_DD", "MKTCAP", "FORN_HD_MKTCAP", "MKTCAP_RTO", "LIST_SHRS", "FORN_HD_SHRS", "LIST_SHRS_RTO"` to `"AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG"`.
- You want to convert the values like `"2,208,300,470,743,887"` to the numbers like `[2,208,300,470,743,887]`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
// This is from your question.
var json = {"block1":[{"TRD_DD":"2021/12/22","MKTCAP":"2,208,300,470,743,887","FORN_HD_MKTCAP":"740,740,079,190,175","MKTCAP_RTO":"33.54","LIST_SHRS":"61,701,475,584","FORN_HD_SHRS":"11,191,374,601","LIST_SHRS_RTO":"18.14"},{"TRD_DD":"2021/12/21","MKTCAP":"2,200,896,109,564,335","FORN_HD_MKTCAP":"736,382,905,931,787","MKTCAP_RTO":"33.46","LIST_SHRS":"61,701,475,584","FORN_HD_SHRS":"11,198,948,564","LIST_SHRS_RTO":"18.15"},{"TRD_DD":"2021/12/20","MKTCAP":"2,191,456,183,748,063","FORN_HD_MKTCAP":"731,379,899,525,089","MKTCAP_RTO":"33.37","LIST_SHRS":"61,698,916,232","FORN_HD_SHRS":"11,215,916,966","LIST_SHRS_RTO":"18.18"}],"CURRENT_DATETIME":"2021.12.22 PM 04:24:06"};

// Object for converting the keys.
var obj = {"TRD_DD": "AAA", "MKTCAP": "BBB", "FORN_HD_MKTCAP": "CCC", "MKTCAP_RTO": "DDD", "LIST_SHRS": "EEE", "FORN_HD_SHRS": "FFF", "LIST_SHRS_RTO": "GGG"};

// Converting keys.
json.block1 = json.block1.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [obj[k], v.includes(",") ? v.split(",").map(e => Number(e)) : v])));

console.log(json)
```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added 1:

About `Another goal I'd like to achieve is to upload it into a google sheet.` in your comment, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
// This is from your question.
var json = {"block1":[{"TRD_DD":"2021/12/22","MKTCAP":"2,208,300,470,743,887","FORN_HD_MKTCAP":"740,740,079,190,175","MKTCAP_RTO":"33.54","LIST_SHRS":"61,701,475,584","FORN_HD_SHRS":"11,191,374,601","LIST_SHRS_RTO":"18.14"},{"TRD_DD":"2021/12/21","MKTCAP":"2,200,896,109,564,335","FORN_HD_MKTCAP":"736,382,905,931,787","MKTCAP_RTO":"33.46","LIST_SHRS":"61,701,475,584","FORN_HD_SHRS":"11,198,948,564","LIST_SHRS_RTO":"18.15"},{"TRD_DD":"2021/12/20","MKTCAP":"2,191,456,183,748,063","FORN_HD_MKTCAP":"731,379,899,525,089","MKTCAP_RTO":"33.37","LIST_SHRS":"61,698,916,232","FORN_HD_SHRS":"11,215,916,966","LIST_SHRS_RTO":"18.18"}],"CURRENT_DATETIME":"2021.12.22 PM 04:24:06"};

// Object for converting the keys.
var obj = {"TRD_DD": "AAA", "MKTCAP": "BBB", "FORN_HD_MKTCAP": "CCC", "MKTCAP_RTO": "DDD", "LIST_SHRS": "EEE", "FORN_HD_SHRS": "FFF", "LIST_SHRS_RTO": "GGG"};

// Converting keys.
json.block1 = json.block1.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [obj[k], v.includes(",") ? v.split(",").map(e => Number(e)) : v])));

console.log(json)

// Put the values to Spreadsheet.
var header = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG"];
var values = json.block1.flatMap(o => {
  var temp = header.map(h => o[h]);
  var max = Math.max(...temp.map(r => Array.isArray(r) ? r.length : 1));
  temp = temp.map(r => {
    if (Array.isArray(r)) {
      return r.length == max ? r : [...r, ...Array(max - r.length).fill("")];
    }
    return [r, ...Array(max - 1).fill("")]; // or return Array(max).fill(r);
  })
  return temp[0].map((_, c) => temp.map(r => r[c]));
});
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the sheet name.
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

- In the above script, if you want to embed the same values for only one value, please replace `return [r, ...Array(max - 1).fill("")];` with `return Array(max).fill(r);`.

### Added 2:

From your following replying,

> One thing is, however, converting to numeric is not what I want. the comma "," does not separate different numbers, but is just a separator for money count, like 1 million dollars (1,000,000$). I want "1,000,000" to "1000000", but not 1 and 000 and 000.

How about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
// Object for converting the keys.
var obj = {"TRD_DD": "AAA", "MKTCAP": "BBB", "FORN_HD_MKTCAP": "CCC", "MKTCAP_RTO": "DDD", "LIST_SHRS": "EEE", "FORN_HD_SHRS": "FFF", "LIST_SHRS_RTO": "GGG"};

json.block1 = json.block1.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [obj[k], v.includes(",") ? v.replace(/,/g, "") : v])));
// or json.block1 = json.block1.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [obj[k], v.includes(",") ? Number(v.replace(/,/g, "")) : v])));

var header = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG"];
var values = json.block1.map(o => header.map(h => o[h]));
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the sheet name.
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tanaike. But in Google Apps Script, it says there is a Syntax error in the line of json.block1 =~~~. I don't know why.

Comment: Another goal I'd like to achieve is to upload it into a google sheet. thanks a lot!

Comment: @JHP Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `But in Google Apps Script, it says there is a Syntax error in the line of json.block1 =~~~. I don't know why.`, I thought that you might disable V8 runtime. If my understanding is correct, please enable V8 runtime with the script editor and test it again. About `Another goal I'd like to achieve is to upload it into a google sheet.`, I couldn't notice this. I apologize for this. Please wait for it.

Comment: @JHP About `Another goal I'd like to achieve is to upload it into a google sheet.`, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected situation on the Spreadsheet. So when I misunderstood your other goal and that was not useful, I apologize, again.

Comment: You are amazing! I enabled V8 runtime, but now it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Sorry, I'm a very beginner in Apps script.

Comment: @JHP Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because when I tested my proposed script using your sample value, no error occurs. About this, you can also test it in my answer. How about this? Your issue is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I added the whole script in Google Apps script above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JHP Thank you for replying and adding your current script. When I saw your script, I noticed the modification point. `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)` returns the object of `HTTPResponse`. I think that this is the reason of your new issue. In this case, please modify `var json = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);` to `var json = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText());` and test it again.

Comment: It works!! Amazing!! One thing is, however, converting to numeric is not what I want. the comma "," does not separate different numbers, but is just a separator for money count, like 1 million dollars (1,000,000$). I want "1,000,000" to "1000000", but not 1 and 000 and 000.

Comment: @JHP Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From `I'd like to change all numbers to numeric not string.` in your question, I have split the value including `,` as the numbers. In this case, I cannot understand your expected situation. So can you provide the sample output situation you expect as the image? By this, I would like to modify the script. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: I embedded a link for the image above. Thanks!!

Comment: @JHP Thank you for replying and adding the sample output image. From your replying, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again. And, if you want to include the header, please modify `var values = json.block1.map(o => header.map(h => o[h]));` to `var values = [header, ...json.block1.map(o => header.map(h => o[h]))];`.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you very much! You are a genius, Tanike!! I want to understand your script someday. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you that I can't accept it yet. It requires me 15 or more reputations but now I've got nine. Soon after getting more reputations, I will do that. Thank you.